# How do I make RSS feeds show images for a blog?

Tags: blog, rss

I'm hosting a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site, tomresing.com on fpweb.net and pushing my blog feed through feedburner at http://feeds.feedburner.com/TomResingsSharePointBlog.

However, my images don't display properly because they are a relative path.

Anyone else experiencing this found a solution?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this that you can provide below?

Comment: No. I still would like to find a way to fix this. Sometimes, I host the images on other sites so the RSS Feed has only absolute links but most of the time I'm too lazy to do that extra step.

Answer (score 1):

The only workarounds seem to be using custom code.

One option is to alter the ListFeed.aspx page [as described here by Duncan Smart](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/04/01/images-broken-when-viewing-windows-sharepoint-services-rss-feeds-in-outlook/) (link is for 2007 but presumably same in 2010). He created an [HTTP response filter](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) to correct the links.

If you absolutely didn't want to modify the out-of-the-box files (which is not best practice) then you may be able to write an HTTP module to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I can't do either of those on my current host and I'm not sure I would do either if I could. However, it does give me the feeling maybe a ListFeed.aspx replacement could work in a Sandbox Solution. Maybe the combination of a custom master page and a web part that iterates through the posts.

Comment: Yes I think in this case that's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to alter the RSS.xslt which resides in the Style Library of the site - this produces the necessary output for the feed.  The feed is generated from a LAYOUTS page which creates an instance of the CQWP using this XSLT, so may be worth a try....bear in mind that this will alter all RSS feeds in the site collection.  Given that you don;t appear to have access to the server it's certainly worth a look.

Comment: Great insight, Steve. Any suggestion on how? I wish I was better at XSLT.

Comment: You can get the current $WebUrl and $SiteUrl from the XSLT parameters passed into the CQWP, so you may be able to use them.  Using those as the base of your URLs you can use the "concat" XSLT function to concatenate the values together.  You may have to have a few attempts to get it right, but should work out for you.

Comment: Is RSS.xslt a Server only solution? I see it in the Style Library on a Server site, but not on my Foundation sites where I have blogs.